# Transform Array of objects with Jolt

Tags: java, transform, jolt

I'm trying to convert one array of objects into output JSON without wrapper key in it using `JOLT`.

**INPUT**

```
{
  "emps": [
    {
      "emp": {
        "empId": "2A68",
        "emailAddress": "abc@xyz.com",
        "name": "abc",
        "userId": "82869",
        "userType": "none",
        "phoneNumber": "1234",
        "rank": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**SPEC I TRIED**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "emps": {
        "*": {
          "empId": "data.result[&1].emps[&1].empId",
          "name": "data.result[&1].emps[&1].name",
          "phoneNumber": "data.result[&1].emps[&1].phone",
          "emailAddress": "data.result[&1].emps[&1].email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "result[]": {
          "*": {
            "emps[]": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
{
  "data" : {
    "result" : [ {
      "emps" : [ {
        "empId" : "2A68",
        "name" : "abc",
        "phone" : "1234",
        "email" : "abc@xyz.com"
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Please copy and paste the above `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` [here](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception)
If I remove `emp` wrapper from input then its working fine as expected but not getting how can I get the same output with `emp` wrapper.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spec

Have to have the first shift, step thru "emps", the array, and then the "emp" object.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "emps": {
        "*": {
          "emp": {
            "empId": "data.result[0].emps[&2].empId",
            "name": "data.result[0].emps[&2].name",
            "phoneNumber": "data.result[0].emps[&2].phone",
            "emailAddress": "data.result[0].emps[&2].email"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "result[]": {
          "*": {
            "emps[]": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```